# ResponsiveSlides button tabs position

Tags: jquery, responsive-slides

I'm using ResponsiveSlides js to create image sliders. However, is that possible to position the bottom button tabs to be within the image?
my test link:
http://websolutions.my/slider-test/
I tried editing the css but cant able to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below property to the UL

```
#slideshow ul {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your css

```
#slideshow ul.centered-btns_tabs{
     position: relative;
     margin-top: -10px;
     margin-bottom: -10px;
     top: -45px;
     z-index: 999;
}
```

[image: center aligned dots]

Comment: Sorry my bad. Edited code -  `ul .centered-btns_tabs` to be read as `ul.centered-btns_tabs`. 

I haven't used  `#slideshow ul` because there are 2 `ul` inside #slideshow. 

Above solution worked because of the margin reset in the other ul element. Its better to add the class.